# Is $ABC - ADC = A(B-D)C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does that only apply if A is invertible? 
With $ ABA^{-1} - ACA^{-1} = A(B-C)A^{-1} $

Comment: Do you mean $ABC - ADC = A(B-D)C$? If so this is just the associative property of matrix multiplication twice

Comment: -1 because question body is grossly inconsistent with the title making definitive answers impossible.  Please edit and I will remove my dv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the matrices have compatible dimensions,
$$ABC-ADC=(AB-AD)C=(A(B-D))C=A(B-D)C$$
None of the matrices have to be invertible.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is $n \times k$, $B$ and $C$ are $k \times m$, and $D$ is $m \times p$, then this always holds since the matrix dimensions permit all of the requisite operations; indeed we may write

$A(B - C)D = A(BD - CD) = ABD - ACD, \tag 1$

since, if $\vec v$ is any $p \times 1$ column vector,

$A(B - C)D \vec v = A(BD \vec v - CD \vec v)$
$= ABD \vec v - ACD \vec v = (ABD - ACD) \vec v. \tag 2$

Note that matrix inversion is used nowhere in the above.